# Grabbing post image - Wordpress PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a function here which will grab the two most recent post and grab the image posted within those two post.  The issue is though, it keeps grabbing the first image of the first post and not also the second:

Code:

```
function getImageFeatured($num) {
  global $more;
  $more = 1;
  $link = get_permalink();
  $content = get_the_content();
  $count = substr_count($content, '<img');
  $start = 0;
  for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++) {
  $imgBeg = strpos($content, '<img', $start);
  $post = substr($content, $imgBeg);
  $imgEnd = strpos($post, '>');
  $postOutput = substr($post, 0, $imgEnd+1);
  $postOutput = preg_replace('/width="([0-9]*)" height="([0-9]*)"/', '',$postOutput);;
  $image[$i] = $postOutput;
  $start=$imgEnd+1;
}
 if(stristr($image[$num],'<img')) { echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$image[$num]."</a>"; }
  $more = 0;
}

$args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' . getImageFeatured('1')  .'</a></li> ';

}
```

Not to sure why It is only sending out the first image of the first post.

Suggestion and thoughts appreciated.

EDIT:

With Revision:

```
.....above function I posted....   
 global $post;
 $args = array( 'numberposts' => '2' );
 $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
 foreach( $recent_posts as $post ){
    setup_postdata( $post );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="Look '.get_the_title_attribute().'" >' . getImageFeatured('1')  .'</a></li> ';

 }

 wp_reset_postdata();
```

This does not work either for me.  It seems if I use the `setup_postdat...` it wont process but if I remove it it goes through but does not do what I ask, but does what I stated the problem to be.

Answer (score 0):

get_the_content is getting the content of the post in the loop. You may run the function on both posts but it still gets the content of the post that's in the loop.

The function you've written needs some serious improvement but for the sake of getting it working in the quickest manner possible replace the existing foreach loop with:

```
global $post;

foreach( $recent_posts as $post ){
    setup_postdata( $post );
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="Look '.get_the_title_attribute().'" >' . getImageFeatured('1')  .'</a></li> ';

}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Could you give me some tips for my function to be improved?

Comment: sidebar.php - I was creating a wigdit in it.

Comment: OK are you setting the featured image for the post and if so is there a problem in using that?

Comment: No its an image within a post that the function grabs and displays from that post.  MY issue is that when trying to do this it always displays the image from the first post.  I have this same function except its meant for catagorys and similar post and it works perfect its just for this it wont and i don't know why